# steps to get to programming android apps

Tags: android-intent

So I'm a beginning programmer working from the ground up.

I have some basic knowledge of programming using darkbasic programming. (for games).

I am reading more and more but I ultimately want to make android apps.

So my question is what are the steps in learning that will help me get to android app developement?

Like do I start out with C or C++ and then go to java and so on or is there another course of action to take?

Can you go straight to learning java/C++ and start making apps?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit wide in scope, but here's a 5000 ft overview.

While you'll end up writing your Android apps in Java, the structure of your application will be a bit different from a regular Java program. If you're unfamiliar with basic Java concepts, you should start by writing quite a bit of regular Java to get yourself familiar with object oriented programming. Android makes use of threads and events, so these are also concepts that you can begin to work with before jumping into Andriod development. Once you're ready, start going through the Android samples distributed with the SDK to get a feel of the Android development environment. Depending on the type of game you'd like to develop, there will be plenty of libraries out there so you don't have to redevelop the wheel, but I'd make sure you have a solid understanding of Java and Android before jumping in on anything bigger.

Comment: you def answered my question pretty well for the most part. thank you for that. so you are suggesting that i start out with java as my first full programming language and then move on to android and skip learning soemthing like C or C++ and moving in that direction? will learning java help me with programming basics and such also along the way or do i need other materials to suppliment? thanks again

Comment: +1 I agree that learning Java is the best first step towards learning Android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an established engine like libGDX.  That might help you get to your feet quickly while also helping you focus on your game content.  You can always move up from there if you're interested in creating an engine from scratch.

You can find starting materials for libGDX here: 
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html